# Laravel дополнительная обработка запроса

Tags: php, laravel

Сделал `php artisan create:request TableCreateRequest`
Прописал правила:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'login' => 'nullable',
            'pass' => 'nullable',
            'google_maps' => 'nullable',
             #https://www.google.com/maps?q=52.2484,21.0026
             #В google_cords должно передать 522484:210026
            'google_cords' => 'nullable',
        ];
    }
```

Делаю `Table::create($request->validated());` в бд всё создаётся, всё хорошо. Мне теперь нужно в ходе запроса если есть `request->google_maps`, взять координаты и помести в `google_cords`. Можно ли это сделать как-то в модели или в TableCreateRequest?

Comment: Можно в реквесте через метод `prepareForValidation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `TableCreateRequest` добавляем:

```
    private function getGoogleCords($google_maps)
    {
        $result = substr($google_maps , 30 );
        $result = explode(",", $result);
        $cord1 = str_replace('.', '', $result[0]);
        $cord2 = str_replace('.', '', $result[1]);
        return $cord1 . ':' . $cord2;
    }

    protected function prepareForValidation()
    {
        $google_maps = $this->request->get('google_maps');
        if ( $google_maps )
        {
        $this->request->set('google_cords', $this->getGoogleCords($google_maps));
        }
    }
```